# Get value of select box using delegate

Tags: jquery

I am using delegate function of jQuery to apply 'onChange' event for select box. The code is working correctly and triggering 'onChange' event -- But I am not able to get value of select box.

Below is my code

```
$("body").delegate('#reportDrill').change(function(){

    alert($(this).val());     // Not alble to get value by $(this).val()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use correct syntax for `.delegate()`:

```
.delegate( selector, eventType, handler(eventObject) )
```

so the selector must be the first argument then follow by the event:

```
$("body").delegate('#reportDrill','change',function(){
    alert($(this).val());     // Not alble to get value by $(this).val()
});
```

but you should use **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead of `.delegate()` because:

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method

so you can do:

```
$("body").on('change','#reportDrill',function(){
    alert($(this).val());     // Not alble to get value by $(this).val()
});
```